# Linux crontab execution “who -u am i” not take effect

Tags: cron

system：centos

I failed to execute "who-u am i" in crontab, and none of the logging，but execute "who" in crontab was successful and printed to / var/spool/mail/root

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9VC3.jpg)

Comment: I think you are talking about the command `whoami` ?

Comment: yes，I already know why.Because in crontab is performed in a new environment, can be interpreted as no user login status, the use of "who-u am i" to view user login information is no result

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh he's talking about 'who'. It takes arguments, -u shows only users are logged in and the arguments 'am i' make it return only the calling user's information. Using the -u argument is indeed why it fails.